# more than a dozen pages in

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

What does the bolded phrase mean? Specifically, what is the definition of "in" there?

> A dispatcher began looking through pages on the National Center for Missing and Exploited Children website, and **more than a dozen pages in**, came across a missing poster for Connerjack Oswalt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"more than a dozen pages in", means that after a dispatcher *read* the website for *more than a few dozen pages*, reached a point where he/she came across a missing poster for Connerjack Oswalt.

You should be able to use "more than a dozen pages *on*", [in this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+dozen+pages+on%2Ca+dozen+pages+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20in%3B%2Cc0)

It seems "on" is more reasonable, as we say "on a website" rather than "in a website." - @Apollyon

Comment: Could we say "more than a dozen pages on"?

Comment: You should be able to use "on". look [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+dozen+pages+on%2Ca+dozen+pages+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dozen%20pages%20in%3B%2Cc0) @Apollyon

Comment: It seems "on" is more reasonable, as we say "on a website" rather than "in a website."

Comment: ah yes that explains how more people in the Ngram use "on"

Comment: Small correction: "he/*she*", or, simply, "they" :)

Comment: I don't think that Ngrams search is useful, because it's going to capture a lot of stuff like "He wrote a dozen pages on the French Revolution", which is a completely different usage.

Comment: @DialFrost You are right that **on** could be used, but I think that both **on** and **in** relate to distance travelled (in this case, the number of pages covered) rather than "located on" as you suggest.